# Can't copy a Google Doc using Google Docs API (no 'copy' attribute)

Tags: python, google-docs-api

I can't seem to copy a doc from Google Docs but I can edit a doc I have already created and I can create a blank document. With the code below, I get AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'copy'. Can anyone offer some insight? The copy code is found here: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents and the starter code is found here: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

# The ID of a sample document.
document_id = f'{sample_document_ID}'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Docs API.
    Prints the title of a sample document.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'googleDocsCredentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)


    copy_title = 'Copy Title'
    body = {
        'name': copy_title
    }
    drive_response = service.documents().copy(
        fileId=document_id, body=body).execute()
    document_copy_id = drive_response.get('id')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

In order to copy the Google Docs file, it is required to use `files().copy` method of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python_1) I think that the reason of your issue is this.

By this, your script can be modified as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)


copy_title = 'Copy Title'
body = {
    'name': copy_title
}
drive_response = service.documents().copy(
    fileId=document_id, body=body).execute()
document_copy_id = drive_response.get('id')
```

To:

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)  # Modified

document_id = '###'  # Please set the Document ID.
copy_title = 'Copy Title'
body = {
    'name': copy_title
}
drive_response = service.files().copy(   # Modified
    fileId=document_id, body=body).execute()
document_copy_id = drive_response.get('id')
print(document_copy_id)
```

#### Note:

- In your case, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` is used. If an error of `File not found` occurs when you run the script and even when the Google Document is put in your Google Drive, please modify `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, and delete the file of `token.pickle`. And the, please reauthorize the scopes again. By this, new scopes can be used.

#### Reference:

- [Copying an existing document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python_1)

Comment: That worked, thank you for the explanation! I did need to modify 'auth/drive.file' to 'auth/drive' per your recommendation as well.

Comment: @nickshep Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Great post. I did modify 'auth/drive.file' to 'auth/drive' and I solved my problem. Honestly I find the Google API non particularly clear and user-friendly at the moment...