# Copy docs' content using Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to copy all content between an initial and a final index in [Google Docs API in Python](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python), despite if it is text, image, table, etc. I couldn't find any reference about copying contents regardless of the content type using Google Docs API. Does anyone know how can I implement it?

For example, suppose I want to duplicate the content below inside a Google Doc by copy and paste:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
[some-image]
[some-table]
consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

I want to have this output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
[some-image]
[some-table]
consectetur adipiscing elit.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
[some-image]
[some-table]
consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with 2 different options to do this:

**Method 1**

To copy a complete Google Doc, you can use the [files().copy](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python_1) method of Drive API. Something like this:

```
copy_title = 'Copy Title'
body = {
    'name': copy_title
}
drive_response = drive_service.files().copy(
    fileId=document_id, body=body).execute()
document_copy_id = drive_response.get('id')
```

You can review and find a sample code in the answer to [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879103/cant-copy-a-google-doc-using-google-docs-api-no-copy-attribute)

*Note: You can use this method to copy a part of the document by making a complete copy of the file, and after that, edit the new copy of the document while keeping the original one unmodified. You can use [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) for that*

**Method 2**

You can use the [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) method to get the content between an initial and a final index. Something like [this](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python):

```
try:
        service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
        document = service.documents().get(documentId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()
```

Note: If you use the documents.get you will get the raw data of the document. You will need to search for the ["body"](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) of the document. There you will see the content of the document with the parts of the document with their respective initial and a final index. After that, you can also use a [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) to paste the information into a new document or the same document as on this case.

**Reference:**

- [Copy an existing document.](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/documents#python_1)
- [Method: documents.get.](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate.](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [Guide for documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)
- [Example of how the raw data looks with document.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents)
- [Another question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61879103/cant-copy-a-google-doc-using-google-docs-api-no-copy-attribute)

Comment: Actually, I only need to **copy** a part of a document. The `document.get()` function that you suggested only **gets** the entire document. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: I edited part of the answer, with more information about the `document.get()`. You can select which part you want to copy with the respective initial and a final index for that part.